# Are there different functions $f(x),g(x)$ and $h(x)$ with these conditions

Tags: functions

If real functions f, g, and h have the same domain A, and

(i) $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$, for all $x \in A$,

(ii) f and h are continuous at $ a = x \in A$,

(iii) $f(a) = h(a)$

Are there *different* functions $f(x),g(x)$ and $h(x)$ with satisfying the above conditions?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there are:

$f(x) = -x^2$

$g(x) = 0$

$h(x) = x^2$

And $a = 0$

In particular those conditions are often used to apply the squeeze theorem to a limit of a function. For example, when calculating $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} $. We can see that in a neighbourhood of $0$ we have $\cos {x} \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le 1$ and thus at the point $x = 0$ it makes only sense that $\frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$.